# Play iTunes song in my iPhone application

Tags: iphone, itunes, avplayer, ipod, mpmediaitem

I am developing a music based iPhone application.
I listed the songs in iPod library in my application.
But when I tried to play songs from iPod library using AVPlayer, some songs are playing and some songs are not playing. When I checked, it seems that the not playing songs are paid songs from the iTunes.
Is there any problem for paid songs playing. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use the [mediaplayer framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MediaPlayer_Framework/_index.html) not AVPlayer

Comment: Thanks for your response. But using AVPlayer I could play other songs, even the songs downloaded from iTunes as free.